# Can't overclock GPU using amdgpu driver on archlinux

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics

I am using open-source driver amdgpu on my arch linux. I read that I can overclock my GPU by writing to this files: `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od` and `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_mclk_od` to adjust my GPU's core and mem frequencies accordingly. But when I write, for example 5, to any of this files it resets it to 0 and clocks aren't applied.

Also I have this file `pp_dpm_sclk` and `pp_dpm_mclk` the contents of sclk is: `0: 300Mhz 
1: 483Mhz 
2: 662Mhz 
3: 841Mhz 
4: 881Mhz 
5: 914Mhz 
6: 939Mhz 
7: 947Mhz *`

And I can actually switch between this frequencies, but I want to go way beyond 947 and I don't understand how to do this.

Question is why `pp_mclk_od` and `pp_sclk_od` resets to 0 when I try to give some percentage boost (0-20) to it? And how can I add more frequencies to `pp_dpm_sclk` and select it from there if I can't achieve it with od?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the frequencies and voltage by modifying the file `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage`

first: This holds the presets for `pp_dpm_sclk` and `pp_dpm_mclk`.

Second check the current settings:

```
sudo cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage
```

You should see something similar to this:

```
OD_SCLK:
0:        300MHz        750mV
1:        588MHz        765mV
2:        980MHz        987mV
3:       1100MHz        950mV
4:       1100MHz        950mV
5:       1100MHz        950mV
6:       1100MHz        950mV
7:       1100MHz        950mV
OD_MCLK:
0:        300MHz        750mV
1:       1000MHz        800mV
2:       1970MHz        950mV
OD_RANGE:
SCLK:     300MHz       2000MHz
MCLK:     300MHz       2250MHz
VDDC:     750mV        1150mV
```

Example to set 1280Mhz at 950mV (**check your output above for possible ranges!**):

```
sudo echo "s 7 1280 950" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage
```

Then to apply the changes:

```
sudo echo 0 > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od
sudo echo 1 > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od
```

These are all the settings I use on my crypto mining card which is an AMD Radeon RX570 in case it's useful to anyone.

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm1_enable
echo manual > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
echo 200 > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm1 # Fan speed
echo 4 > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_power_profile_mode # Compute Mode

echo "s 3 1100 950" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo "s 4 1100 950" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo "s 5 1100 950" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo "s 6 1100 950" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo "s 7 1100 950" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage

echo "m 2 1985 950" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage

echo 0 > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od
echo 1 > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od

echo 0 > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_mclk_od
echo 1 > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_mclk_od
```

Comment: Is there any way to go further than `OD_RANGE`? For my GPU the default values are already at maximum, but on Windows it was no problem to go higher...

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities to consider:

1)not all cards support this function

2) In Ubuntu at least, you have to modify those files as root not just use "sudo". So make sure you:

sudo su

to become root user. then:

echo "5" >> ./pp_mclk_od     (for example)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the inadequacy of ``sudo`` (contrasted to ``root``) or provide a reference?

Comment: @Scott he's wrong, sudo is perfectly adequate

Comment: @radman no he's right. `sudo` gives `Permission Denied`

Comment: @Scott running a command with `sudo` makes the command passed to `sudo` run with root privileges, but it does not make your *shell* run with root privileges.

When you run the command

    sudo echo foo > bar

Only the `echo foo` bit runs as root. The redirection happens in your shell under your user. As an alternative to `sudo su` you can use `sudo sh -c "echo foo > bar"` or `echo foo | sudo tee bar` (in the latter case, `tee` is used instead of shell redirection.)