# Cannot overclock AMD GPU on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, amd-graphics, amd

I am trying to overclock the memory on my GPU with AMDGPU Pro 18.40 driver.

Nonetheless, `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage` is an empty file and I cannot write to it.

When I try

```
echo "m 2 1600 950" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage
```

as root it produces the following error:

```
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

I have `amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xffffffff` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`.

I have also tried running:

```
echo manual | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
```

My question is based on the answer to the following question: [Can't overclock GPU using amdgpu driver on archlinux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404780/cant-overclock-gpu-using-amdgpu-driver-on-archlinux)
The author claims that this method works, however it obviously does not.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install this:
https://github.com/BoukeHaarsma23/WattmanGTK

and then I ran it, and it told me the value I needed to pass to amdgpu.ppfeaturemask.
In my case on a Vega 64 the value is 0xfffd7fff

And yea you add that to grub :)